# resolv.conf always empty

Tags: linux, dns, network-interface, embedded, resolv.conf

I have 2 different embedded devices...an old one running TI arago Linux and a Xilinx device (petalinux).

On both I see the same outcome when adding `dns-nameservers` to `/etc/network/interfaces` and reconfiguring the network with `/etc/init.d/networking restart` or rebooting the device: 
The `/etc/resolv.conf` file always stays empty.

No `dhclient`, `resolvconf` package, `network-manager` daemon or `mdns` are present in the system.

Here the `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# /etc/network/interfaces -- configuration file for ifup(8), ifdown(8)

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1
```

and `resolv.conf`:

```
[root@linux:~] ls -l /etc/resolv.conf 
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root           20 Feb  3 18:17 /etc/resolv.conf -> /var/run/resolv.conf
[root@linux:~] ls -l /var/run/resolv.conf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            0 Feb  3 18:17 /var/run/resolv.conf
```

While executing `/etc/init.d/networking restart`, both devices call basically `ifdown -a` and then `ifup -a`, being both `ifup` and `ifdown` busybox utilities in this case.

In case mentioning the immutable file attributes solution: I don't want to generate manually the `resolv.conf` file and change the file attributes to make it immutable (`chattr +i`), because it seems completely against how the system was designed. Why is then `resolv.conf` stored in volatile memory (generated by populate-volatile.sh) in the first place, if it should be permanent?

Thanks for any hints!

**Update: found the solution, but will leave the question, for the sake of somebody searching for it.**

Answer (score 1):

Create a script in `/etc/network/if-up.d/dns` with this content (in this example only `eth0` is taken into account):

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$IFACE" = "eth0" ];then
for NS in $IF_DNS_NAMESERVERS; do
R="${R}nameserver $NS
"
done
echo "$R" > /etc/resolv.conf
fi
```

Make it executable with `chmod +x /etc/network/if-up.d/dns`.

Everytime you reboot the device or restart the networking services, `resolv.conf` will be recreated. Works like a charm!

PS: If you use another directive/naming than `dns-nameservers` in `/etc/network/interfaces`...for example `my-dns`, then replace `$IF_DNS_NAMESERVERS` with `$IF_MY_DNS`. Although it's cool to know, I would rather stick to conventions and use `dns-nameservers`.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is a good solution. Do you have `mdns` running on these systems?

Comment: @tripleee No, mdns is not installed in the system. Can you share a more extended answer on why you are not convinced this is a good solution or do you have a better one? Thanks.